# How to Merge Two CSV Files in Python Based on Common Column

Tags: python, csv, merge

I am attempting to merge CSV files together.

Now I have 28 country need test, data in File-1.csv 
And Every country has maybe 10 test Scenario,data in File-2.csv 
I need the merge file, then I can use python to create N*M(280) unit cases.

**File-1.csv**

```
Case,Country,URL,Message1,Message2

01,UK,www.acuvue.co.uk, registersuccess,Fail

02,LU,www.acuvue.lu, denaissance,Vousdevez

03,DE,www.acuvue.de,,,
```

**File-2.csv**

```
Case,Country,Scenario,Mail,Name,Password

UK,InvalidMail,TEST,Susan_UK,Password1#

UK,InvalidPass,susan@test.com,Susan_UK,TEST

LU,InvalidMail,TEST,Susan_LU,Password1#

DE,InvalidMail,TEST,Susan_DE,Password1#
```

I want Python merge those two CSV file as below:

```
Case,Country,URL,Message1,Message2,Scenario,Mail,Name,Password

010,UK,www.acuvue.co.uk,registersuccess,Fail,InvalidMail,TEST,Susan_UK,Password1#

011,UK,www.acuvue.co.uk,registersuccess,Fail,InvalidPass,susan@test.com,Susan_UK,TEST

020,LU,www.acuvue.lu,denaissance,Vousdevez,InvalidMail,TEST,Susan_LU,Password1#

030,DE,www.acuvue.de,,,InvalidMail,TEST,Susan_DE,Password1#
```

How could I do this in Python?

Comment: Let us know what you have tried so far.- I do not see any `Case` value in `File-2.csv`

Comment: You'll have to post a code attempt, even if it's a bad attempt, as it's part of the rules for asking questions. Give it a try and post what you've tried and show where you're stuck.

Comment: Use the `csv` module for reading/writing CSV data. Use a dictionary to map the key values to the data in a row and use this to merge the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading both CSV into two seperate list and use zip_longest to merge two lists and store merged list into single list.